# How to save all graphs from Rstudio History

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, rstudio

I m looking for a way to save all the graph from the plot windows in the Rstudio GUI.

example :

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, size = cyl)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, facets = vs ~ am)
```

I now have 4 graph in the plot windows.. I want to save each plot into a file.
I tried ggsave, the "plot" parameter in ggsave seems to be promissing , but I dont find how to browse all available plots in RstudioGD.

Any idea ?

edit :
I know I can do this :

```
a<-qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars)
b<-qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
c<-qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, size = cyl)
d<-qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, facets = vs ~ am)
ggsave(a ...)
ggsave(b ...)
```

But I dont want to create R objet.

Comment: What output do you want? do you want pdfs? Do you want `ggplot` objects that you can load later? This is not clear from your question. Whatever you are trying to save, I suspect that you will be better off putting together a script to save the objects rather than using the utilities of rstudio.

Comment: I dont need ggplot objet, png, pdf.. is ok.

Comment: You can do `ggsave(qplot(.....),....)`, that'll save you from making an object.

Answer (score 0):

To write out pdfs or pngs, take a look at `?pdf` and `?png`. The general process is

```
# start pdf device
pdf(file=<path/filename.pdf>, height=<number>, width=<number>)
# first plot, on first page of pdf
print(qplot(...))
# second plot, on second page of pdf
print(qplot(...))
# more plots
...
# close graphics device
dev.off()
```

I usually keep each graphic in separate files, so my process usually looks like this:

```
# start pdf device
pdf(file=<path/filename.pdf>, height=<number>, width=<number>)
# print plot
print(qplot(...))
# close graphics device
dev.off()
```

and repeat.

Always be sure to call dev.off() after you are finished graphing.